# Jquery dropdown menu changes font weight on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I've made a menu with a dropdown in jQuery and everything works fine besides when you view it in safari on mac it changes the font weight when the dropdown shows.

I'm pretty clueless in terms of what i need to change in order to fix it. Can you guys give me a hand, would be appreciated:

You can see the live version: autooffer.dk (hover "mærker") and notice the other menu change font weight

jQuery:

```
  /* DROPDOWN & MENU ANIMATIONS */ 

var mindicator = $('.dropdown_indicator');
mindicator.hide();
var dropdown = $('.dropdown')
dropdown.hide();   

$(".hover_brands").hover(
      function () {
         dropdown.finish().slideDown(200);
         /*mindicator.css("display","block");*/
      }, 
      function () {
         dropdown.finish().slideUp(200);
        /* mindicator.css("display","none");*/
      }
);

dropdown.mouseover(
  function () {
    dropdown.stop(true, true).slideDown(0);
    /*mindicator.css("display","block");*/
  }
); 

dropdown.mouseleave(
  function () {
    dropdown.finish().slideUp(200);
    /*mindicator.css("display","none");*/
  }
);   

 mindicator.mouseover(
  function () {
    dropdown.stop(true, true).slideDown(0);
  }
); 

mindicator.mouseleave(
  function () {
    dropdown.finish().slideUp(200);
  }
);
```

CSS:

```
#menu
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background: #3e6f9b;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#menu ul
{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#menu ul li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 35px;
    color: #fff;    
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s; /* Safari */
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
}

#menu ul li:hover
{
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s; /* Safari */
    transition: 0.3s;
    background: #36536e;
}

#dropdown
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    background: #28abe3;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="menu" class="fix_menu_hover">     
            <ul class="nav">
                <a href="#PAGE#(HOME)" class="anchor_line">
                    <li>Vælg bil</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#PAGE#(TILBUD)" class="anchor_line">
                    <li>Tilbud</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#PAGE#(MAERKER)">
                    <li class="hover_brands">Mærker</li>
                </a>
            </ul>       
        </div>
   <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown"> 
        <ul>#LOOP_CARMAKES_ACTIVE#
            <a href="#PAGE_CARMAKE#">
                <li><div class="dropdown_dot"></div> 
               <span class="move_dropdown_txt">#CARMAKE_NAME#</span>
               </li>
            </a>
            #END#
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

Comment: You could include this example in a jsfiddle (making it easy for people to see it in action)

Comment: Where is dropdown menu in your HTML?

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ao0yg39t/) , Indeed no dropdown visible!

Comment: As @Jaap said, that would be helpful. [I've started one here for you](http://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/adntL8a5/), but it's not functioning yet. I can't help but notice that you have event handlers on the `dropdown` and `dropdown_indicator` classes, but no HTML elements with those classes./

Comment: sorry guys i added the html for the dropdown. i forgot it. There is some custom tags includede looping the content in the dropdown (ignore that)

Comment: i didnt include all the css in the dropdown because i didnt think it relevant to the issue but i can update the code if needed

Comment: I think you need to include all your CSS code because I still can't see your dropdown! @fragstar

Comment: its live on autooffer.dk if you hover "mærker". if you have a mac you'll see the font weight change

Comment: all add the rest of the code when im back tomorrow at the office.

Answer (score 0):

Font rendering issue, try this:

```
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```